# RAID Server Data Recovery

Tags: hard-drive, raid, data-recovery

Need to recover data from a ~2010 vintage Windows RAID array server (Dell PowerEdge T710).  What is the best way to get the data back?  The data is valuable so while I'm willing to take some risk by doing it DIY rather than hiring a data recovery service, I'd like to minimize risk of data loss and comments on likely level of data risk of doing this DIY are welcome.

Details:
There are 8 plugged-in drives that are 2TB each.  Not sure of the RAID configuration, Windows or BIOS or other software details.  Do have the admin username and pw.  System was formerly in use as a Windows network server of some kind.  The system hasn't been powered on in years.  No physical damage has occurred to the drives as far as I'm aware.  The system itself will power up, but will not boot into Windows, not sure why.  It appears that the server itself may have software or hardware issues.  It has been in an insufficiently dry environment.  Initially (yesterday), when trying to boot an ascii screen came up on the monitor that asked questions about BIOS etc.  Now, no screen comes up but the system appears to power up (lights come on, fans spin).

Data recovery companies seem to indicate that it will likely cost >$10k if they do it.

Is there a relatively straightforward way to pull out the drives, put them into a new enclosure of some kind, clone the data from the drives, and reconstruct it into the full file structure that is on the drives?

I have looked at other related questions, but haven't found one that seems to answer this particular scenario.

Thank you

Comment: you can try removing the RAID controller card and putting it another machine

Answer (score 0):

This is a good problem description:

> Initially (yesterday), when trying to boot an ascii screen came up on the monitor that asked questions about BIOS etc.

Your mainboard battery most likely failed.

Enter your BIOS, take a note of all settings or save your settings to a secondary drive (not your RAID array), maybe an USB stick.

Replace the battery after disconnecting mains power.
Reconnect mains, restart the machine and go into BIOS and load the setup defaults.
Compare with your saved settings (those may be wrong due to battery failure).

See if it boots.

Check all boot-related settings.
Make sur you boot from your RAID controller.

See what gives.